# Continuity of $f(x)=\lfloor x\sin \pi x\rfloor$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $f(x)=\lfloor x\sin \pi x\rfloor$ (where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer that is at most $x$) is $f$ continuous at any point? Also prove whether it's continuous or not using the precise definition of continuity.

Comment: Draw a graph for it near zero and see what it looks like.   If there are intervals where it is constant, then of course it will be continuous at interior points of those intervals.

Comment: Please show us your working on the first three parts and use Mathjax

Comment: $f(x)$ is continuous whenever $x\sin\pi x$ is not an integer.

Comment: $f(x)$ is obviously continuous at $0$.

Comment: If $g(x)=x\sin \pi x$ then $f$ is continuous at $x$ when either $g(x)$ is not an integer, or when $g(x)$ is an integer and $g'(x)=0$ and $g''(x)>0.$ $g'(x)=0$ means $\pi x=-\tan(\pi x).$ And $g''(x)\geq 0$ means $$2\cos\pi x\geq \pi x \sin \pi x=-\frac{\sin^2\pi x}{\cos \pi x}$$ which is true if and only if $\cos\pi x\geq 1.$ (We don't need to worry about when $\cos \pi x=0$ since then $x$ is a half-integer, and $x\sin\pi x = \pm x$ is not an integer.)